# flask upload file API without filename

Tags: flask

The file upload API requires the specification of filename. Is there an example of the flask API that just post the file content with the filename?

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/

Answer (score 0):

You have to inspect the "Request" class! https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the file name in your Flask endpoint if you don't want to, just process the data you need. You have few different ways to access the data with [Request object](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request), depending on how you sent the data to server:

- use [request.files](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.form) if you will send the file through some HTML form or using `-F` flag with `curl`.
- use [request.data](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.data) to read raw data as string in case mimetype can not be handled by Flask/Werkzeug (e.g. no `Content-Type` header).
- use [request.get_data()](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.get_data) to read buffered data as a bytestring (e.g. when you use `-d` flag with `curl`).
- use [request.stream](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.stream) if the incoming form data is not encoded with known mimetype, although docs say that "Most of the time it is a better idea to use `data` which will give you that data as a string".